# Praw: Where, oh where, have the self.texts all gone?

Tags: praw

I've been trying to recreate an old project, and one of the attributes I used to be able to access (in 2.1.12, I think) was praw.objects.Submission.body, or the text of a self-text post. It seems that in 2.1.19 that attribute doesn't exist, or at the very least has been renamed to something unintuitive. How do you access the text of a self-text submission with the current version of praw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was more of a personal error. the `praw.objects.Submission.selftext` asset still exists, but isn't visible through `dir()` introspection.